# Can a C# Console App Contain Multiple Sub or Child Console Apps?

Tags: c#, .net, console, console-application

I'm not sure if what I was to do is possible. I'm not a C# guru but I manage to make a living. Over the years I've written and accumulated dozens of console apps that perform otherwise tedious tasks. Everything from cleaning junk data from SQL Server databases, changing filenames in a defined directory, creating zip archives and sending emails.

Most of the apps are built on .Net Framework 4.7. What I'm wondering is if there is a way I can combine all of these apps into a single console application? I would want it to have some sort of menu of available commands as well as descriptive help section for each command and its arguments.

Can I do this? Any tutorials come to mind? Thanks!

Comment: This is a really broad and subjective question. You can combine the applications, you can link the .exe's into a new application (they're just executable DLLs after all) and call their main functions without even recompiling the existing tools. Then build your new application to have the menus and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can right click the Solution in the Solution Explorer in VS and add a project, then in your main call them based on conditions like:

```
using (var process1 = new Process())
{
    process1.StartInfo.FileName = @"..\..\..\ConsoleApp1.exe";
    process1.Start();
}

using (var process2 = new Process())
{
    process2.StartInfo.FileName = @"..\..\..\ConsoleApp2.exe";
    process2.Start();
}

Console.WriteLine("We Just ran two console apps inside of a console app ;)");
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: I like this except I wanted to stay away from multiple .exe's. Maybe importing the projects into class libraries would work? Then I'd still have to sort out being able to return to a main menu...

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use parallel and multi-tasking instead of run multi-app?
You can run multi-task.